# Why is timezone displayed as a number?

Tags: date, timezone

This is an OpenSuse Leap 42.1 and I don't know why or how this happens:

```
$ date
Tue 18 Apr 10:49:34 -03 2017
```

The timezone appears as -03 (or -02) instead of a meaningful name (In my case, BRT/BRST). Tried to search that but this seems to be so obscure that the results are always in the form *"how to change timezone"*

EDIT:
Replies to comments:

```
$ date +%Z
-03
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2017-04-18 11:38:26 -03
  Universal time: Tue 2017-04-18 14:38:26 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2017-04-18 14:38:26
        Timezone: America/Sao_Paulo (-03, -0300)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: What is the output of `date +%Z`

Comment: What is the output of `timedatectl` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how it's now defined at the IANA official standard timezone database

See ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2017b/southamerica

The name for the timezone in Winter time is `-03`. That corresponds to the UTC offset. It's more useful than things like `CET` that are ambiguous (mean different things to different people).

That apparently changed recently. Compare ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2017a/southamerica (2017-02-28) with ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2016j/southamerica (2016-11-23) that had `BRT` instead.

The [`NEWS` file for the 2017a release](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2017a/NEWS) states:

> [...]
>       Switch to numeric time zone abbreviations for South America, as
>       part of the ongoing project of removing invented abbreviations.
>       This avoids the need to invent an abbreviation for the new Chilean
>       new zone.  Similarly, switch from invented to numeric time zone
>       abbreviations for Afghanistan, American Samoa, the Azores,
>       Bangladesh, Bhutan, the British Indian Ocean Territory, Brunei,
>       Cape Verde, Chatham Is, Christmas I, Cocos (Keeling) Is, Cook Is,
>       Dubai, East Timor, Eucla, Fiji, French Polynesia, Greenland,
>       Indochina, Iran, Iraq, Kiribati, Lord Howe, Macquarie, Malaysia,
>       the Maldives, Marshall Is, Mauritius, Micronesia, Mongolia,
>       Myanmar, Nauru, Nepal, New Caledonia, Niue, Norfolk I, Palau,
>       Papua New Guinea, the Philippines, Pitcairn, Qatar, Réunion, St
>       Pierre & Miquelon, Samoa, Saudi Arabia, Seychelles, Singapore,
>       Solomon Is, Tokelau, Tuvalu, Wake, Vanuatu, Wallis & Futuna, and
>       Xinjiang; for 20-minute daylight saving time in Ghana before 1943;
>       for half-hour daylight saving time in Belize before 1944 and in
>       the Dominican Republic before 1975; and for Canary Islands before
>       1946, for Guinea-Bissau before 1975, for Iceland before 1969, for
>       Indian Summer Time before 1942, for Indonesia before around 1964,
>       for Kenya before 1960, for Liberia before 1973, for Madeira before
>       1967, for Namibia before 1943, for the Netherlands in 1937-9, for
>       Pakistan before 1971, for Western Sahara before 1977, and for
>       Zaporozhye in 1880-1924.
>       [...]

Usually, you'd be able to specify the names for Winter and Summer time and the rules for when to change from one to the other by hand in the `TZ` variable, but it looks like for Brazil, it's not really possible as according to that timezone database:

> http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2007-2010/2008/Decreto/D6558.htm
>    [t]he DST period in Brazil now on will be from the 3rd Oct Sunday to the
>    3rd Feb Sunday. There is an exception on the return date when this is
>    the Carnival Sunday then the return date will be the next Sunday...

There's no way to specify this kind of exception in the simple `TZ` rule specification.

Comment: Seems like they may have overlooked the fact that putting an abbreviation in the tzdata file had effectively trained everyone that it *is* the standard representation.

Comment: DST is currently defined as third sunday in October to the third sunday in February, if that weekend is not Carnival. Otherwise, we get an extra week.

Comment: @user666412, that's already mentioned at the end of the answer.

Comment: True. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/clock` with following options and reboot it

```
HWCLOCK="-u"
SYSTOHC="yes"
TIMEZONE="Europe/London"
DEFAULT_TIMEZONE="US/Central"
```

Note:
Mention the timezone as per your timezone

Comment: This seems to be very distribution dependent, I guess you didn't check the current distribution of the user