# How to set the timezone of a Linux host to BRT (Brasilia Time)?

Tags: linux, centos, date

I've a scenario that needs the timezone on the host to be BRT which is currently PST. I'm expecting the result of `date` to appear like `Wed Jan 30 19:30:36 BRT 2020`

I've checked the `/etc/localtime` which is currently linked to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`. I tried changing this to all of the following [*] one by one, but none of them are giving me BRT. I see either one or two hours less/more.

Am I missing anything here? or Is there any other way to set the timezone to BRT?

[*]

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/West
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/DeNoronha
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/Acre
```

Comment: Are you looking for `America/Sao_Paulo`?

Comment: I tried that already but it did not help. Tried again now to show the output. `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo`. After doing this, I see the time as `Mon Feb  3 06:58:10 -02 2020` but not BRT. This is one hour later than BRT time.

Comment: I get `-03` with `America/Sao_Paulo`. The missing abbreviation is probably because [nobody has added the abbreviation to the tz database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/search?q=BRT&unscoped_q=BRT) yet.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how `-03` for you. Could you also double check the Hyperlink you added please? It's not pointing me to an empty github page.

Comment: Try `America/Bahia` that's `-03` all year around. The rule (in Brazil) now is to use numbers, not BRT.

Comment: Thank you. I see `-03` now. So for now I see the right time but just the abbreviation is not appearing which should not be the issue I believe. I will test my issue scenario now.

Comment: I was editing my coment while you wrote yours, please update and re-read.

Comment: Thanks @Isaac . It makes complete sense to me. I am continuing to work on my issue scenario with this set-up.

Answer (score 2):

You would use special commands for it, e.g.:

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/Sao_Paulo
```

But also see [chosen answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359684/why-is-timezone-displayed-as-a-number) having to say that there is a shift towards not displaying abbreviated timezone names.

So you might be getting a display of `-03` instead of the expected `BRT`.

Finally, I don't know what is your specific case for setting a timezone in CentOS. But if the server is going to be ever accessed by *any* people outside Brazil, you're better off stick to UTC.

Instead of setting the whole server to non-UTC timzone, you can *run* something "in Brazil time" using cron. For that, just put the `CRON_TZ=America/Sao_Paulo` in your cron table. Then you can specify Brazilian times in your cron definitions.

Comment: Actualy, the timezone that stay at `-03` all year round is `America/Bahia` (the first capital of Brazil). São Paulo has DST time changes.

Comment: I believe the DST will still be observed with the command above. The `-03` is only current display.

Comment: DST is **not** observed in Bahia. I lived there a bit more than a year.

Comment: Where you see `Bahia` in my answer? It is `America/Sao_Paulo`

Comment: Were you not answering my initial comment about Bahia?